# How can I see user information other than the logged-in user in Django?

Tags: django, templates

I'm using Django 2.2 and PostgreSQL. After logging in, the user has a page where they can see other users' information. However, all users' login information appears on the page. I want to see information from other users except him. How can I do that?

templates/neighbor.html

```
{% csrf_token %}
{% if neighbor_list %}
{% for neighbor in neighbor_list %}
<div class="card border-left-success  py-2" style="background-color:    rgb(240,240,240);">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
      <div class="col mr-2">
         <div class="text-left">
            <strong><p><a href="{% url 'store:neighbor_detail' neighbor.user.username %}">{{neighbor.user.first_name}} {{neighbor.user.last_name}}</a></p></strong>
             <p><strong><i class="fa fa-user"> : </i></strong>{{neighbor.user.username}}</p>
             <p><strong><i class="fa fa-envelope"> : </i></strong>{{neighbor.user.email}}</p>
              <p><strong><i class="fa fa-phone"> : </i></strong>{{neighbor.phone}}</p>
              <p><strong><i class="fa fa-fax"> : </i></strong>{{neighbor.fax}}</p>
              {% if neighbor %}
              <p><strong><i class="fa fa-map"> : </i></strong>{{neighbor.neighborhood}}, {{neighbor.avenue}}, {{neighbor.street}}, {{neighbor.block}}, No.{{neighbor.number}}, Kat.{{neighbor.storey}}, {{neighbor.district}}/{{neighbor.province}}</p>
              <p>{{neighbor.profile_image}}</p>
              {% endif %}
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

store/views.py

```
from store.models import StoreOtherInfo
def neighbor(request):

    neighbor_list = StoreOtherInfo.objects.all()
    return render(request,'store/neighbor.html',{"neighbor_list":neighbor_list"}
```

store/models.py

```
class StoreOtherInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    fax = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    neighborhood = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    ...

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `exclude(user=request.user)`.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def neighbor(request):
    neighbor_list = StoreOtherInfo.objects.all().exclude(user=request.user)
    return render(request,'store/neighbor.html',{"neighbor_list":neighbor_list})
```

In the code above I've used the `login_required` decorator to make sure the user is logged in. An alternative is to check `user.is_authenticated` and only do `exclude()` when the user is logged in.

```
@login_required
def neighbor(request):
    neighbor_list = StoreOtherInfo.objects.all()
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        neighbor_list = neighbor_list.exclude(user=request.user)
    return render(request,'store/neighbor.html',{"neighbor_list":neighbor_list})
```

Comment: I can sign in. I want to see the information of other users except the logged in user.

Comment: `exclude(user=request.user)` means `StoreOtherInfo` where `user=request.user` is not included in the results. You need the `@login_required` or `if request.user.is_authenticated:` because you can't do `exclude(user=request.user)` when `request.user` isn't logged in.

Comment: You're super, it works exactly the way I want. Thank you so much.